# C# passing canvas from XAML to another class not using constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, encapsulation

Is there any way to pass a canvas not directly form MainWindow class to another class not using constructor or setter?
What I mean is:

```
class MainWindow{
   public MainWindow(){
    // here we got our canvas property
   }
}

public interface IDraw{
   void draw(Canvas c);
}

class Map : IDraw{

   public Map(){
     draw(/*canvas*/);
   }
   void draw(Canvas c){

   }
}
```

Unfortunately on my way stands a factory creating Map. I've no way to modify this. Any solutions?

Comment: How do you use `IDraw`?

Comment: That is a problem. I'd like to use it in my Map class. Except for that to draw a map I call a draw method in MainWindow class

Comment: It doesn't clear, what's the problem. Does your `Map` implement `IDraw`, or you *want* it to implement `IDraw`? What cannot be modified - factory, `Map`?

Comment: Map objects are generated by class called MapFactory, which reads the configuration from XML file. MapFactory is singleton class with static method getInstance(), and method Map getMap(int gameLvl)

Comment: So, what's the problem to create `Map` using factory, and call `map.draw`, passing canvas from `MainWindow`?

Comment: How can you pass canvas from main window not changing the factory and using setters?

Comment: `Map.draw` method, which implements `IDraw.draw`, accepts `Canvas`, isn't it? If so, just call `draw(yourCanvas)`.